# Maven dependencies for web service client using axis1

Tags: web-services, maven, axis

Inside a maven project, I would like to use some classes that were already generated by eclipse from a working web service wsdl. These are the proxy classes that make all the web service client connections.

The problem is to find out what are the maven dependecies I need to set in order to get it to work.

Adding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

There are no eclipse errors, but when I run it I get:

> Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in
> class file javax/xml/rpc/ServiceException

I think the problem is I got the api but not the implementation of the web services. Which are the maven dependencies or how can I find them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem got solved by using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The first and last one are the same so you can remove one and the groupId should be org.apache.axis since it was relocated...

Answer (score 2):

Thee axis dependency is mentioned twice and I needed:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```